# Prerequisites for deployment of rust release binary

Tags: rust

What are the requirements for deployment of rust release binary that you generate out of cargo release command. If I copy the executable file on a machine, will it work out of the box? or does it require gcc be installed on the target machine?

Comment: As with any executable, using the command `ldd ./path/to/my/executable` shows the list of library dependencies that must exist on the target. (assuming you are on Linux here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't use any crates and don't link to FFI libraries yourself, then your executable should be standalone. E.g. a simple "hello world" will work out of the box.

In a real project you would use external crates, and all depends on the crates you use. Most of them don't have any extra dependencies and will work out of the box too, but some crates require the corresponding libraries to be installed (most notably for GUI).

On Unix systems, the command: `ldd ./target/release/my_crate` will list the required libraries:

```
> ldd ./target/release/hello
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffefd736000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f0299dc0000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f0299db6000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f0299d95000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f0299d90000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0299bd0000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0299e5e000)
```

Those are all standard libraries that should be already installed on any system, so this program has no particular requirements and should work out of the box anywhere.

On Windows, you can use [Dependencies Walker](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) to find out the required libraries.

Comment: Thanks for posting the detailed answer. Specially ldd command.