# How can i make Rust program become self-contained?

Tags: windows, rust, rust-cargo

How can i make my Rust program become self-contained. It mean my program will run independent in every Windows machine.

i tried to use:

```
cargo build --release
```

But when i run on another computer, i still missing some dll:

[image]

Can someone help me?

Comment: Not a windows expert, but I don't think you can statically link DLLs (the name alone seems to indicate as much).

Comment: Did you have any dependencies requiring linking with libusb? If so, how did you do it? Was it using VCPKG?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76586303/5397009

Answer (score 1):

The [`dumpbin.exe` program](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference?view=msvc-170) can help.

If you run `dumpbin.exe /dependents path\to\my\program.exe`, you should see a list of the `.dll` libraries which are required by your program.
Then you have to rerun the command `dumpbin.exe /dependents path\to\the\library.dll` recursively for each of the reported libraries.
This is quite tedious, but I guess you can automate that with a script.

Then, when you install your program to a new computer, you can place in the **same** directory as your executable all the collected libraries.
When we launch an executable on Windows, the libraries are searched in several standard directories **and** in the directory where stands this executable.
All the libraries you provided should be found here.

Alternatively, you can simply launch your executable on the target and each time the missing library message appears, you find it in the source computer and put it next to the executable on the target computer.
The problem with this alternate solution is that if the target computer already contains a non-standard library that you need, then you will not notice it, and it may be missing on another target computer.

Comment: [Dependencies Walker](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) can scan recursively if you want to get all the required DLLs at once.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your target, `rustc` links libraries differently, as specified [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1721-crt-static.md):

- `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` links dynamicly to [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/s/libc/)
- `x86_64-unknown-linux-musl` links staticly to [musl](https://www.musl-libc.org/)
- `x86_64-pc-windows-msvc` links dynamicly to [MSVCRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/c-run-time-library-reference?view=msvc-170)

The RFC linked above includes a feature - static CRT linkage, that change whether the C standard library is linked dynamically or statically.

To enable it in your project:

- Create a `.cargo\config.toml` file in the root folder:
- Add the following into it:

  ```
  [target.x86_64-pc-windows-msvc]
  rustflags = ["-Ctarget-feature=+crt-static"]
  [target.i686-pc-windows-msvc]
  rustflags = ["-Ctarget-feature=+crt-static"]
  ```
- Build the executable, and then try running it on another computer.

If you wish for this to be the default for all your projects, you can put it in
`%USERPROFILE%\.cargo\config.toml` instead.

Comment: I don't think `libusb` is in the standard C runtime, or am I misunderstanding what this feature does?